# Magento 2 independent cron job queue

Tags: magento2, cron, queue

Sending newsletters via cron job queue, blocks sending important emails to the customers, is there a way to make independent cron job queue which will be run only if core queue is empty or something like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Manually Run Cron Job**

```
sudo php bin/magento cron:run --group="customgroupname_cron"
```

Comment: Yeah I know about that, but If I want to cron automatically makes the order of his jobs, could I do that through group names in the code?